# How do i check, if all characters from a set of strings are unique per index elegantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm coding TicTacToe in Python3 and try to implement a elegant way to check, if the last move ends the game. The gamefield consists of a dictionary with the position described with 2 chars as key (l = left, m = mid, r = right, t = top, b = bottom) and the Player as value (' ' = None, 'X', 'O')  So i tried something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
class TicTacToe:
    corners = ('tl','tr','bl','br')
    edges = ('tm','ml','mr','bm')
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = {i + j:' 'for i in ['t','m','b'] for j in ['l','m','r']}
        self.currentplayer = ''
        self.lastmove = ''
    def printBoard(self):
        vals = list(self.board.values())
        print('l m r ')
        print(*vals[:3],sep='|', end=' top\n')
        print('-+-+-')
        print(*vals[3:6],sep='|', end=' mid\n')
        print('-+-+-')
        print(*vals[6:],sep='|', end=' bot\n')
    def roundcount(self):
        return len([i for i in self.board.values() if i != ' '])
    def move(self,mve):
        self.currentplayer = 'O' if self.currentplayer == 'X' else 'X'
        if not self.board.get(mve):
            return 'impossible move'
        if self.board[mve] != ' ':
            return 'already taken'
        self.board[mve] = self.currentplayer
        self.lastmove = mve
        return f'Move done! Now its {self.currentplayer}\'s turn:'

    ############################
    #Here is the important part#

    def calcwin(self):
        curmoves = [k for k,v in self.board.items() if v == self.currentplayer]
        cornermvs = [m for m in curmoves if m in self.corners]
        edgemvs = [m for m in curmoves if m in self.edges]
        if self.lastmove in self.corners:
            for i in combinations(cornermvs,2):
                if i[0][0]==i[1][0] and i[0][0] + 'm' in edgemvs:
                    return self.currentplayer
                elif i[0][1]==i[1][1] and 'm' + i[0][1] in edgemvs:
                    return self.currentplayer
                elif 'mm' in curmoves:
                    return self.currentplayer            
        if self.lastmove in self.edges:
            # I gave up on this point
            pass
        if self.lastmove == 'mm':
            pass
```

But if i did it this way i thought i could already just check the whole gameboard, so i came up with a much smaller approach:

```
    def calcwin(self):
        curmoves = [k for k,v in self.board.items() if v == self.currentplayer]
        possiblecomb = [c for c in combinations(curmoves,3) if c[0][0] == c[1][0] == c[2][0] or c[0][1]==c[1][1]==c[2][1]]
        if len(possiblecomb)>0:
            return self.currentplayer
```

which apparently only checks for non diagonal wins:

```
Field: 
l m r 
X|X|X top
-+-+-
O|X|O mid
-+-+-
O|O|X bot

possiblecomb:
[('tl', 'tm', 'tr')]
```

Is it possible to include the diagonal checking as elegant? To make this work, i'd need to check if all characters per index of all 3 strings in the combination are different. Like:

```
Field
l m r 
X|X|X top
-+-+-
O|X|O mid
-+-+-
O|O|X bot

possiblecomb:
[('tl', 'tm', 'tr'), ('tl', 'mm', 'br')]
```

Comment: @stovfl The new calcwin function stores this in possiblecomb, which are the coordinates of the winning moves of the last player. But it only detects the horizontal and vertical wins. Not the diagonal ones.

Comment: Checked myself and get 'WIN': `if all(self.board[key] == 'X' for key in ('tl', 'mm', 'br')):`

Comment: @stovfl thats actually a pretty good idea, i didnt thought about. I just have to do it for each diagonal (that means twice), but i'd still be elegant. Thank you